# PHP Multidimentional Array error

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

We are working on a Monopoly game in PHP as a class project and none of us cab figure this out. 
We need to create and use a multidimentional array for the properties in the game. Below is an example of what this looks like.

```
$arr2=array();
$prop=array(1,3,6);
$cost=array(60,60,100);

$stuff=$prop[0];
$arr2[$stuff][9]=$cost[0];
echo"$stuff --- $arr2[$stuff][9]"; //(this is line 64)
```

When we try to run this, we get this output.

```
Notice: Array to string conversation in ... line 64
1 --- Array[9]
```

Why is it giving us "Array[9]" instead of 60?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: `echo "{$stuff} --- {$arr2[$stuff][9]}";` try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complex array and object expressions need to be wrapped in curly braces `{}`:

```
echo "$stuff --- {$arr2[$stuff][9]}";
```

Or break out of the quotes and concatenate:

```
echo "$stuff --- " . $arr2[$stuff][9];
//or
echo $stuff . " --- " . $arr2[$stuff][9];
```

See [**Variable Parsing - Complex (curly) Syntax**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

Answer (score 1):

echo a PHP variable has its own convention, you can echo a variable as string but sometime it will not work perfectly, So you need to use `.` concatenation of the variable with string.

```
echo $stuff." --- ".$arr2[$stuff][9]; //1 --- 60
```

If you want to use variables inside echo then must use `{}`.

```
echo "{$stuff} --- {$arr2[$stuff][9]}"; //1 --- 60
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try something like this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change this part

```
echo"$stuff --- $arr2[$stuff][9]"; //(this is line 64)
```

with this

```
echo $stuff." --- ".$arr2[$stuff][9]; //(this is line 64)
```

You can check it out in this [Fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9da264308a898511e2ffc1a6676759defd8c600a)